# In Salesforce how do you add a New Contact to a already existing account?

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I already have an account in Salesforce , now how do I add New Contact/'s programmatically to the existing Account . Is there a way to do it directly using SOQL / DML Apex ?

I was searching if its possible to just hold details of an account into as Object and then add the new contact .

Thanks
OQ.

Answer (score 0):

Do a SOQL on Account and use it's id to map the contact you creating to your existing account.

```
try{

    List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account Where Name =:your_acc_Name LIMIT 1];
    Contact c = new Contact();
    c.AccountId = accList[0].Id;
    c.LastName = 'lname';
    c.FirstName='fname';
    c.Phone='1234';
    insert c;
}catch(DmlException e) {
    System.debug('An unexpected error has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
}
```